# How to implement multi-producer multi-consumer single-buffer model?

Tags: locking, producer-consumer

There is one buffer, multiple producers and multiple consumers. Any producer(only one) can write the buffer when it is empty. Any consumer(only one) can read the buffer when it is full. How to implement such a model?
I tried using pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal. But I didn't find a solution.

Comment: If the buffer contains more than one element and the producers can only write to the buffer when it is empty then the buffer will never be filled and no consumer will ever be able to read from the buffer. Change the conditions. Producers should be able to write to the buffer when it is not full. Consumers read from the buffer when it is not empty.

Comment: @JimRogers  We can assume that every read to the buffer would read all elements in the buffer, and every write to the buffer would write until the buffer is full.

Answer (score 0):

The following multiple producer multiple consumer single buffer implementation is implemented using Ada. The protected object is the buffer. There are two producers and two consumers. The protected object implicitly handles all the locking and condition variables.

The producer task type, consumer task type and protected object are all defined in an Ada package.

The package specification is:

```ada
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Producer-consumer with bounded buffer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
generic
   Capacity : Positive;
package Bounded_PC is
   task type Producer is
      entry set_id(Id : in Positive);
      entry Stop;
   end Producer;

   task type Consumer is
      entry set_id(Id : in Positive);
      entry Stop;
   end Consumer;

end Bounded_PC;
```

The package body contains the implementation of the task types and the shared buffer.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

package body Bounded_PC is
   subtype Index_T is Positive range 1..Capacity;
   type Buf_Array is array (Index_T) of Integer;

   ------------
   -- Buffer --
   ------------

   protected Buffer is
      Entry Write(Item : in Integer);
      Entry Read(Item : out Integer);
   private
      Buf : Buf_Array;
      Write_Index : Index_T := 1;
      Read_Index  : Index_T := 1;
      Count       : Natural := 0;
   end Buffer;


   protected body Buffer is

      entry Write(Item : in Integer) when Count < Capacity is
      begin
         Buf(Write_Index) := Item;
         Write_Index := (Write_Index mod Capacity) + 1;
         Count := Count + 1;
      end Write;

      entry Read(Item : out Integer) when Count > 0 is
      begin
         Item := Buf(Read_Index);
         Read_Index := (Read_Index mod Capacity) + 1;
         Count := Count - 1;
      end Read;

   end Buffer;

   --------------
   -- Producer --
   --------------

   task body Producer is
      Value : Integer := 0;
      Me : Positive;
   begin
      accept Set_Id(Id : in Positive) do
         Me := Id;
      end Set_Id;

      loop
         select
            accept Stop;
            exit;
         else
            select
               Buffer.Write(Value);
               Put_Line("Producer" & Me'Image & " wrote" & Value'Image);
               Value := Value + 1;
            or
               delay 0.001;
            end select;
         end select;
      end loop;
   end Producer;

   --------------
   -- Consumer --
   --------------

   task body Consumer is
      Value : Integer;
      Me : Positive;
   begin
      accept Set_Id(Id : in Positive) do
         Me := Id;
      end Set_Id;

      loop
         select
            accept Stop;
            exit;
         else
            select
               Buffer.Read(Value);
               Put_Line("Consumer" & Me'Image & " read" & Value'Image);
            or
               delay 0.001;
            end select;
         end select;
      end loop;
   end Consumer;

end Bounded_PC;
```

The condition for each entry call is declared in the protected body.

```ada
entry Write(Item : in Integer) when Count < Capacity

entry Read(Item : out Integer) when Count > 0
```

The main procedure for this program is:

```ada
with Bounded_PC;

procedure Main is
   package Int_Pck is new Bounded_Pc(10);
   use Int_Pck;

   P1 : Producer;
   P2 : Producer;
   C1 : Consumer;
   C2 : Consumer;
begin
   P1.Set_Id(1);
   P2.Set_Id(2);
   C1.Set_Id(1);
   C2.Set_Id(2);
   delay 0.01;
   P1.Stop;
   P2.Stop;
   delay 0.01;
   C1.Stop;
   C2.Stop;
end Main;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But I don't understand your answer and I have to implement the model with C/C++.

Comment: Would you like me to edit the answer above to include more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a solution:

```
bool buffer_empty = true;

// consumer thread:
pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_lock);
while (buffer_empty) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_full, &buffer_lock);
}
// consume
buffer_empty = true;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_lock);


// producer thread:
pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_lock);
while (!buffer_empty) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_full, &buffer_lock);
}
// produce
buffer_empty = false;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_lock);
pthread_cond_signal(&buffer_full);
```